# Filtering list inside Observable collection

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I want to filter `List <Notification>` which is inside `Observable` collection by the specified event.

Here is a Retrofit call:

```
@GET("/notifications")
Observable<NotificationCollection> getNotifications(@Query("page") Integer page);
```

`NotificationCollection` model:

```
class NotificationCollection {
         var items: List<Notification>? = null
         var pagination: Pagination? = null
}
```

`Notification` model:

```
class Notification {
        var event: String? = null
        var id: Long? = null
        var data: NotificationData? = null
}
```

In my helper class, I return `Observable` to interactor:

```
override fun getNotifications(page: Int): Observable<NotificationCollection> {
        return service.getNotifications(page)
    }
```

I tried a couple of approaches:

```
override fun getNotifications(page: Int): Observable<NotificationCollection> {
return service.getNotificationsTimeline(page)
    .filter { it.items?.get(0)?.event == "STORY"}
}
```

Here I want to apply a predicate to all list items and not only to the ones I define by an index. Is there a way to make something like `.filter { it.items.event = "STORY"}` ?

Another approach I tried using `flatMap` here which makes more sense to me but I don't see the way how to map my filtered result to the original response type of `Observable<NotificationCollection>` and not to the `Observable<Notification>` like here :

```
return service.getNotifications(page)
    .flatMap { Observable.fromIterable(it.items) }
    .filter {it.event == "STORY"}
```

The easiest way would be to apply `filter` function in my presenter class with `flatMap` but I want to generalize my solution because the method in the helper class is called in different places. So I want to make the list filtered here.

So, is there a way to filter the list inside `Observable` collection and return the original response type of `Observable<NotificationCollection>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use 'filter' and 'any' together.

```
class Test {
    init {
       val testList = listOf(
               TestData("1","1", listOf("1a")),
               TestData("2","2", listOf("2b")),
               TestData("3","3", listOf("3c")))

        val result = testList.filter { item ->
            item.c.any { it == "STORY" }
        }
    }
}

data class TestData(val a: String, val b: String, val c: List<String>)
```